# Outlook add-in C Sharp: While loop question

Tags: c#, outlook, outlook-addin

I'm writing a quick little add-in for Outlook that will check my email every x minutes and process the messages. This is my first add-in so I'm a little unsure of the order of runtime events, but the problem I'm having is that I'm using a while loop with a sleeper on my addin load event, which causes outlook to never fully open.

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    while (true)
    {
        CheckMail();
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(100000);
    }
}
```

Is there a way I can fully open Outlook before executing this loop?

Comment: The startup method _has to_ end so you can't put an endless loop in it. You can start a timer in it that will exectute every x time. Have a look at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try hanging it off of a reminder event rather than sleeping it.  To do this create a reminder.  When it fires this code will get called.  You can then throw        `CheckMail();` in there.  This is in VBA so you will have to convert it.

```
Private Const REMINDER_SUBJECT As String = "CHECKEMAILREMINDER"

Private Sub Application_Reminder(ByVal Item As Object)
  Dim oTask As Outlook.TaskItem
    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.TaskItem Then
        Set oTask = Item

        If oTask.Subject = REMINDER_SUBJECT Then

            oTask.ReminderTime = DateAdd("m", 1, Now)
            oTask.Save

        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

I searched for quite some time looking for a way to have regular events in outlook without using a reminder in order to archive my e-mail but this is the only solution I found.